# Passando uma variável de javascript para session

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Gostaria de saber, como faço para enviar um valor que tenho em javascript para uma @session. no caso seria mais ou menos assim:

Tenho uma variável:

> var id = $(Pessoa).val();

este ID queria utilizar em uma variável de sessão, porém tentei fazer assim:

> @Session["Pessoa"] = id;

mas quando rodo a página da erro no javascript. como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Precisava levar para o controller,  mas já arrumei uma outra solução. Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Por que não manda esse id pro controller utilizando o json e coloca ele numa viewbag, e usa ela na view?

Comment: Consegui aqui aos 45 do segundo tempo passando por parâmetro no link. Amanhã eu respondo minha pergunta própria pergunta kk Valeu mano boa sorte pra nós

Comment: Ah, aí sim, nice ;)